# Change checkbox option value to 1 or 0 in Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using **Contact Form 7 in WordPress** and have the following field:

`<div class="checkbox">[checkbox subscribed default:1 "Send me occasional email updates"]</div>`

"Send me occasional email updates" becomes the input label and the value when this option is selected is "Send me occasional email updates".

**I want the value to be 0 or 1**.

I cannot seem to find a way to do this.

There is an "acceptance" field you can use that does this but it is more for terms & conditions acceptance as it requires the checkbox to be ticked - whereas I am giving the option to opt in/out so I cannot use that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use such shortcodes in the form for checkbox to send value="1":

```
[checkbox optout use_label_element "Opt-Out of Insights and Communications|1"]
```

Then to show original value in the mail message you'll need to use:

```
[_raw_optout]
```

Works ofr me with latest wp and cf7

Answer (score 0):

I have a very hacky solution.  We had the same issue with a subscription checkbox, the entire label was passed through to the email and the user requested a simple yes/no.  I used a combination of a hidden field and jQuery to accomplish this.

First, add an additional checkbox with values "yes" and "no" (or whatever you want).  Put it in a container that's hidden on your form:

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
                        [checkbox updates id:updates "Please check here to receive updates ...."]
                    </label>

<div class="checkbox-inline hidden hidden-contact-check">
[checkbox updateshidden default:2 id:updateshidden "yes" "no"]
</div>
```

Then a bit of javascript that will keep the appropriate checkbox checked in the hidden field:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#updates.wpcf7-checkbox input').click(function() {

        $('#updateshidden.wpcf7-checkbox input[value=yes]').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
        $('#updateshidden.wpcf7-checkbox input[value=no]').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked') === false);

    });
});
```

Then finally in the Mail tab for CF7 you use the field [updateshidden]

```
Subscribe: [updateshidden]
```

This will pass through a yes/no to the email rather than the label you provided.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about the syntax of contact form 7 of WordPress, but usually this works:

```
<input id='testName' type='checkbox' checked = 'checked' value='Yes' name='testName'>Send me occacional updates
```

Let me know if it does not suit your purpose.

Comment: Sorry - I cannot change the HTML which is output through the shortcode to add a value.